# Server Connection Error 500 with Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have installed Jupyter Lab but when I launch it I get an error: "Server Connection Error Invalid response: 500 Internal Server Error"

My python set up is Anaconda which probably has something to do with this.

Full error message from command line:

> jupyter lab
>
> [I 11:09:41.874 LabApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled
>   0.2.8
>
> [I 11:09:41.884 LabApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from
>   /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
>
> [I 11:09:41.884 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
>   /anaconda/share/jupyter/lab
>
> [W 11:09:41.887 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled,
>   manually loading...
>
> [I 11:09:41.888 LabApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from
>   /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
>
> [I 11:09:41.888 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
>   /anaconda/share/jupyter/lab
>
> [I 11:09:41.896 LabApp] Serving contents
>
> [I 11:09:41.896 LabApp] 0 active kernels
>
> [I 11:09:41.896 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
>   http://localhost:8888/?token=ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237
>
> [I 11:09:41.896 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut
>   down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
>
> [C 11:09:41.897 LabApp]
>
> ```
> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
> to login with a token:
>     http://localhost:8888/?token=ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237
> ```
>
> [I 11:09:42.090 LabApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated
>   connection from ::1
>
> [W 11:09:42.740 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status
>   without nodejs
>
> [E 11:09:42.748 LabApp] Unhandled error in API request
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py",
>   line 516, in wrapper
>           result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line
>   238, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
>   line 126, in get
>           if model['type'] == 'directory' and content:
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>
> [E 11:09:42.753 LabApp] {
>         "Host": "localhost:8888",
>         "Connection": "keep-alive",
>         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162
>   Safari/537.36",
>         "Authorization": "token ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         "Accept": "*/*",
>         "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
>         "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
>         "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|a0d1ccab|73a01490f127ec24c30835607aea1050|1520242814;
>   username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1521630582|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MTQwZDBhNzZlYzY5NDIxZWIyNzUxMWNkMzczZWNiMWU=|79900638f4dc105393e048f2236331a6f46520ff43b4ff010066d0196b260a00\""
>       }
>
> [E 11:09:42.753 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1521630582746
>   (::1) 5.28ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
>
> [W 11:11:05.761 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status
>   without nodejs
>
> [E 11:11:05.770 LabApp] Unhandled error in API request
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py",
>   line 516, in wrapper
>           result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line
>   238, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
>   line 126, in get
>           if model['type'] == 'directory' and content:
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>
> [E 11:11:05.770 LabApp] {
>         "Host": "localhost:8888",
>         "Connection": "keep-alive",
>         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162
>   Safari/537.36",
>         "Authorization": "token ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         "Accept": "*/*",
>         "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
>         "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
>         "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|a0d1ccab|73a01490f127ec24c30835607aea1050|1520242814;
>   username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1521630665|23:username-localhost-8888|44:Y2JlODAxNzA3MDY4NDIwYWE4YTM5NGZlZDNhMThlYjE=|7ae8038d90bbf8f4d44811f23462b14cce1e930fc7f000b31c01e68a84245818\""
>       }
>
> [E 11:11:05.770 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1521630665767
>   (::1) 1.21ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
>
> [E 11:12:45.773 LabApp] Unhandled error in API request
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py",
>   line 516, in wrapper
>           result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line
>   238, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
>   line 126, in get
>           if model['type'] == 'directory' and content:
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str [E 11:12:45.774 LabApp] {
>         "Host": "localhost:8888",
>         "Connection": "keep-alive",
>         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162
>   Safari/537.36",
>         "Authorization": "token ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         "Accept": "*/*",
>         "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
>         "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
>         "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|a0d1ccab|73a01490f127ec24c30835607aea1050|1520242814;
>   username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1521630765|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ODFhYWQ3ZDU5OWE5NDdmYTlkODhkNmMxYzg2MDlkYWI=|0dc6d8a192c6e5494080ca950923b1b291086c2d87c2fbcd709488469ac03370\""
>       }
>
> [E 11:12:45.774 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1521630765770
>   (::1) 1.80ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
>
> [E 11:14:26.770 LabApp] Unhandled error in API request
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py",
>   line 516, in wrapper
>           result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line
>   238, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
>   line 126, in get
>           if model['type'] == 'directory' and content:
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>
> [E 11:14:26.771 LabApp] {
>         "Host": "localhost:8888",
>         "Connection": "keep-alive",
>         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162
>   Safari/537.36",
>         "Authorization": "token ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         "Accept": "*/*",
>         "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
>         "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
>         "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|a0d1ccab|73a01490f127ec24c30835607aea1050|1520242814;
>   username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1521630865|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MDNhNGVlZjQxZGYxNGZmN2I3ZjIyNmYzMTI2MDE5ZDI=|700d7876594cb797ba50d10173ed9132af5988cb1c0dc82aba0ded957fef24e5\""
>       }
>
> [E 11:14:26.772 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1521630866769
>   (::1) 1.59ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab [E 11:16:07.776 LabApp]
>   Unhandled error in API request
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py",
>   line 516, in wrapper
>           result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line
>   238, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>         File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
>   line 126, in get
>           if model['type'] == 'directory' and content:
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>
> [E 11:16:07.777 LabApp] {
>         "Host": "localhost:8888",
>         "Connection": "keep-alive",
>         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162
>   Safari/537.36",
>         "Authorization": "token ad00b52a346b46663662980c13b3da3edb1ecf8614ef1237",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         "Accept": "*/*",
>         "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
>         "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
>         "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|a0d1ccab|73a01490f127ec24c30835607aea1050|1520242814;
>   username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1521630965|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MDc0MjlmODBlYTM4NDBjZDhlZjgyOTEzYTA2OTExMmU=|997eec50aacef9512c6adb31f8badfa3145c86c13b0d45914585a5a62c852e11\""
>       }
>
> [E 11:16:07.777 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1521630967773
>   (::1) 1.71ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: so.. this problem has gone away. But I do not know what solved it, as the list of things changed includes getting a new laptop!